# List of reactions within chapter

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros

Using the `chemmacros` package, deploying the `\listofreactions` within a chapter preamble does not appear to have any effect.  I would like to present a list of only those reactions appearing within the chapter.

Comment: The `chemmacros` package does not provide that functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attempt using partial list utility from `titletoc` package.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usechemmodule{reactions}

\makeatletter
\def\ttl@partiallor{plr}

\apptocmd\ttl@writepartial
  {\ttl@topartial{lor}{#1}{#2}}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% you can still use \listofreactions to print full lor
%\listofreactions

\chapter{title}
\startlist{lor}
\printlist{lor}{}{}
\begin{reaction} A -> B \end{reaction}
\begin{reaction} A -> B \end{reaction}
\begin{reaction} A -> B \end{reaction}

\chapter{title}
\startlist{lor}
\printlist{lor}{}{}
\begin{reaction} A -> B \end{reaction}
\begin{reaction} A -> B \end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

With `titlesec` package, you can auto insert `\startlist` and `\printlist` after each `\chapter` by setting

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

% style based on standard class, see doc of titlesec, sec. 9.2
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
  {20pt}{\Huge}
  [\vspace*{40pt}%
   \normalsize\normalfont
   \startlist{lor}%
   \printlist{lor}{}{}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{50pt}{10pt}
```

Comment: How can one get a `List of Reactions' heading to print with font size and style matching that of the lor at the beginning of the document, or the lof for that matter?

Comment: @JohnChris In `book` style, the list title produced by `\listofreactions` uses the style of `\chapter*`. The partial list of reactions used under each chapter should use style of `\section*` instead of `\chapter*`. So, you can try `\printlist{lor}{}{\section*{\reactionlistname}}`.